# Pymatching decoder version in sinter package

Tags: error-correction

Does the "Pymatching" decoder of the "sinter" python package use Pymatching 1.0 or 2.0?

https://pypi.org/project/sinter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses whichever version of pymatching you have installed. You can install version 2.0 by

```
pip install pymatching~=2.0
```